# How to use 1 ui-view if there are multiple ui-view elements with the same name?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a html structure like so,

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <a href="#" ui-sref="content-view">Click me</a>
  </div>
  <div ui-view="content-view">Template goes here</div>
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <a href="#" ui-sref="content-view">Click me</a>
  </div>
  <div ui-view="content-view">Template goes here</div>
</div>
```

Two content-wrapper divs with both a ui-view called `content-view`.

And my state config looks like this,

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: ''
  })

$stateProvider
  .state('content-view', {
    url: '',
    views: {
      "content-view": {
        template: '<div>Content</div>',
        }
      },
  })
```

See it in action here > http://plnkr.co/edit/997KbH9beLLHClM0IKb9?p=preview

If a user clicks on one of two `ui-sref` elements both the ui-view 'content-view` elements get triggered and inject the template.

What I would like to see is that only the ui-view in the `content-wrapper` element that gets clicked gets triggered.

Hiding one or the other element wouldn't be a good solution, because then the views will still have to load all the data in them. So I think my best bet is to target the specific ui-view in the same content-wrapper element.

*** Update ***

I've updated my plunker > http://plnkr.co/edit/997KbH9beLLHClM0IKb9?p=preview

I create several rows with content divs in them. Each row has 1 ui-view element. If a user clicks on one of the links it places the template in each view. While I want to target the view that's inside the content wrapper that the user clicked on.

Comment: why don't you use directive for this purpose?

Comment: Could you make a suggestion on how this directive would look?

Comment: take a look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/nvZPyy4HfB4QB9VDolVy?p=preview

Comment: Lookgs good! Thanks, I haven't used Directives that much, but replacing the (limited in this case) functionality of ui-router by the strength of directives was a great way to look at the problem. I was stuck in tunnelvision. If you want, you can answer the question and i'll upvote ya.

Comment: yes I ll do thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of nested views you can use directive here as you have repeating same objects so nested views do not help you that much...

just define a directive which is only for templating (of course you can extend its feature by your needs)..,

```
app.directive('contentTemplate', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div class="content-view">{{vm.movie.title || "No Movie"}} is selected</div>',
    scope: {
      movie: '='
    },
    controller: ContentTemplateController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true
  }
})

function ContentTemplateController() {
  // your directive controller if you need it
}
```

then bind your selected content with directive then whenever you change movie content of directive will be changed as well...

```
<div class="content-wrapper" ng-repeat="movieGroup in movieGroups">
      <div class="content" ng-repeat="movie in movieGroup">
        <button ng-click="movieGroup.selectedMovie = movie;">{{ movie.title }}</button>
      </div>
      <content-template movie="movieGroup.selectedMovie"></content-template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating independent `ui-view` states with the same name is simply not possible with the current model that `ui-router` has provided. The closest possible implementation is probably **[`ui-router-extras`](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras)**'s **[`sticky`](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky)** module. You can create multiple independent(sticky) states by taking advantage of **[multiple named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)** in a state.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/9juhF5CWxGxYnv5N4j4o?p=preview)**

*Javascript*

```
app = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ui.router',
  'ct.ui.router.extras'
]);

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope){}
])

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

  .state('main', {
    url: '/'
  })

  .state('main.sub1', {
    sticky: true,
    views: {
      'sub1@': {
        template: 'sub1<ui-view />'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('main.sub1.part1', {
    template: '.part1'
  })

  .state('main.sub2', {
    sticky: true,
    views: {
      'sub2@': {
        template: 'sub2<ui-view />'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('main.sub2.part1', {
    template: '.part1'
  });

});
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <a ui-sref="main.sub1">main.sub1</a> | 
    <a ui-sref="main.sub1.part1">main.sub1.part1</a>
  </div>
  <div ui-view="sub1">Template goes here</div>
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <a ui-sref="main.sub2">main.sub2</a> | 
    <a ui-sref="main.sub2.part1">main.sub2.part1</a>
  </div>
  <div ui-view="sub2">Template goes here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. This only works if you name your views. But I'm using ng-repeat to render my html. Do you think it's possible to give the ui-view name a dynamic value?

Comment: Can you please provide the entirety of your question? It seems that you're not providing everything there is to the problem.

Comment: I've updated my plunker to show the problem correctly.